# Keyboard accessible hover for dropdown

Tags: razor, drop-down-menu, accessibility

I am trying to make a dropdown on hover/focus be keyboard accessible. The link to dropdown gets focus when I tab to it, but the drop down is not visible. Where am I going wrong? The "`@(tabn++)"` just returns an integer and increases it for next tabindex

```
<li class="level-1 departments" tabindex="@(tabn++)">
      <a tabindex="@(tabn++)" href="/departments" data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger="focus hover">Departments</a>
           <div class="level1Wrapper">
                 <ul role="menu"     >
                    @foreach (RossStores.Models.NavItem navItem in Model.NavItems)
                              {
                                  <li class="level-2">
                                      <a data-trigger="focus" class="disableUrl" tabindex="@(tabn++)">@navItem.Heading</a>
                                          <ul>
                                              @foreach (RossStores.Models.NavItem subNavItem in navItem.NavItems)
                                                    {
                                                        <li><a tabindex="@(tabn++)" role="menuitem" href="@(subNavItem.Url.TrimEnd("/"))">@Html.Raw(subNavItem.Heading)</a></li>
                                                    }
                                            </ul>
                                  </li>
                                        }
                 </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Positive `tabindex` values should only be used if you want to change the tabbing order for an entire page. To make non-focusable elements focusable without changing the rest of the tab order, use `tabindex=0`. Then you don't need to add `tabindex` to focusable elements such as `a`.

Comment: According to Marco Zehe (Mozilla accessibility QA enginee), you should think twice before implementing a menu: [WAI-ARIA menus, and why you should generally avoid using them](https://www.marcozehe.de/2018/09/22/wai-aria-menus-and-why-you-should-generally-avoid-using-them/).